# Sentencia "WHERE" en JAVA

Tags: java, mysql

Tengo el siguiente código en un botón, el cual me muestra datos de una tabla, lo cual funciona correctamente.

Pero quiero meter un where en en el txtCampo para así también poder filtrar por NumEmpleado.

```
String campo = txtCampo.getText();
            String where = "";
            
            if (!"".equals(campo)) {
            
                where  = "WHERE NumEmpleado = '" + campo + "'";
                
        }
            
                try {
            
            DefaultTableModel modelo = new DefaultTableModel();
            jtDatos.setModel(modelo);
            
            PreparedStatement ps = null;
            ResultSet rs = null;
            com.mysql.jdbc.Connection con = null;  
            con = getConnection();
                  
            String sql = "SELECT NumEmpleado, Nombre, Apellidos, Incentivos, Descuentos, Total FROM consulta" + where;
            System.out.println(sql);
            ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
            rs = ps.executeQuery();
            
            ResultSetMetaData rsMd = rs.getMetaData();
            int cantidadColumnas = rsMd.getColumnCount();
            
            modelo.addColumn("Numero de empleado");
            modelo.addColumn("Nombre");
            modelo.addColumn("Apellidos");
            modelo.addColumn("Incentivos");
            modelo.addColumn("Descuentos");
            modelo.addColumn("Total");
            
            
            while (rs.next()){
                
                Object[] filas = new Object[cantidadColumnas];
                
                for (int i = 0; i < cantidadColumnas; i++) {
                    
                    filas[i] = rs.getObject(i+1);
                    
                }
                
                modelo.addRow(filas);
                
            }
            
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.err.println(ex.toString());
        }
```

Al buscar un NumEmpleado me arroja el siguiente error de sintaxis:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '= '100'' at line 1
```

mi where es el siguiente: `where  = "WHERE NumEmpleado = '" + campo + "'";`

¿Cual e la sintaxis correcta para que el where realice su función con lo que se ingrese en el txtCampo?

Saludos y de antemano gracias por su atención.

Comment: Podría ser que el número de empleado sea de tipo Integer, en cuyo caso te sobrarían las comillas simples. De todas formas, insertar valores en el Where directamente es vulnerable a injecciones SQL: https://www.baeldung.com/sql-injection

Comment: Si concatenas `"FROM consulta"` con `"WHERE..."` obtienes `... FROM consultaWHERE ...`. Es decir, te falta un espacio en medio

Comment: Tienes razón Pablo, el problema era el espacio despues de "consulta" 
String sql = "SELECT NumEmpleado, Nombre, Apellidos, Incentivos, Descuentos, Total FROM consulta(espacio)" + where;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No te falta un espacio?  From consultaWHERE